# How to read stack trace or error info generated in .Net program to find root cause of exception

Tags: c#, exception

This is really basic question and may be duplicate. Can anyone tell me how useful error info generated by any program in .Net.

Today I got an error  "Ambiguous match found." while saving entity in database (using EF4)
I can't figure out why this error is coming, what is the root cause. Attached is the snap for same.

[image]
Here is the complete Error Details,

```
System.Reflection.AmbiguousMatchException was unhandled by user code
     Message=Ambiguous match found.
     Source=mscorlib
     StackTrace:
   at System.RuntimeType.GetPropertyImpl(String name, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Type returnType, Type[] types, ParameterModifier[] modifiers)
   at System.Type.GetProperty(String name)
   at IAA.Data.EntityFramework.RepositoryWithTypedId`2.SaveOrUpdate[T](T entity)
   at ABC.XYZ.ApplicationServices.AcknowledgementManagementService.SaveOrUpdate(AcknowledgementFormViewModel acknowledgementFormViewModel) in E:\RA\ABC.XYZ\app\ABC.XYZ.ApplicationServices\AcknowledgementManagementService.cs:line 123
   at ABC.XYZ.Web.Controllers.AcknowledgementsController.Acknowledgements(AcknowledgementFormViewModel acknowledgementFormViewModel) in E:\RA\ABC.XYZ\app\ABC.XYZ.Web.Controllers\AcknowledgementsController.cs:line 68
   at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
   at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClassd.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__a()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
```

InnerException:

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2877000/entity-framework-4-poco-entities-in-separate-assembly-dynamic-data-website

Comment: yeh,  I will follow that link, but still my question is different. Like I want to know how do i find the cause by reading this error information. Like AmbiguousMatchException contains many properties but which one is useful for me trace the root.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hmya, no such luck.  It would be very nice indeed if the Type.GetProperty() method would actually say *which* name was ambiguous.  But it doesn't and you cannot easily find out.  The code lives in the .NET framework and it is optimized, the debugger cannot retrieve the value of the *name* argument.  Your only cue is that your entity model has two properties with the same name.  Something like that anyway.

Comment: thanks for the info,I guess,I need to manually check and fix the causing property.

Answer (score 10):

This means that an `System.Reflection.AmbiguousMatchException` was thrown, and was not handled. It was thrown at `System.RuntimeType.GetPropertyImpl(String name, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Type returnType, Type[] types, ParameterModifier[] modifiers)`, which was called from `System.Type.GetProperty(String name)`, which was called from `IAA.Data.EntityFramework.RepositoryWithTypedId`2.SaveOrUpdate[T](T entity)`,

etc.

Comment: need the name or work around?, as it is really difficult to check each property in entity with more then 100 properties. Also in future if such type of error occurs I can fix it in minutes.

Comment: thanks John, I removed some properties (duplicated in base class and derived class). And it working fine now.

Answer (score 1):

Debugging the .NET Framework can let you move into the call stack to the place where the exception occurs, where you can see local variables.

In Visual Studio 2010, this is as simple as setting Options in the Debugger section.  In Visual Studio 2008, there are instructions [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sburke/archive/2008/01/16/configuring-visual-studio-to-debug-net-framework-source-code.aspx).

Comment: It would be nice to use the VS Debugger but it is not always possible, especially when trying to run down errors in production environments.